# How do I get the machine code of an assembly instruction known at compile time?

Tags: delphi, assembly, shellcode, basm

I want to be able to convert a single line of ASM into shellcode. I.E:

```
CALL EBX
```

How do I go about doing this, and also being able to properly convert this shellcode so that I can store it in a variable in a delphi application. I.E:

```
var ShellCodeArray:  array[0..3] of Byte = ($55,$8B,$EC,$81);
```

Comment: If you're using a language with a built-in assembler, why not use that assembler?

Comment: Various reasons. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: searching for something like that?
http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/executingpreparedshellcodeindelphi

Comment: Change the `var` to `const` and you're there. I really don't understand this question. It seems to me you already know how to do what you ask.

Comment: Only, it should be `const CALLEBX: array [0..1] of Byte = ($FF,$D3);` or if you really mean a variable rather than a constant, `CALLEBX := TBytes.Create($FF,$D3);`

Comment: @Hvd, you're not allowed to distribute Delphi's assembler with your product. `Call ebx` is an *example* of a command Josh would like to convert; we should assume there are arbitrarily many other instructions Josh's program should be able to convert as well, and they cannot all be calculated prior to shipping. Josh, "shellcode" is a code-injection term, but the rest of the world just calls it *machine code*, and to convert assembly language to machine code, you use an assembler. You can either write an assembler yourself, or find one that you're allowed to distribute.

Comment: @RobKennedy That's not how I read the question, nor as far as I can tell how the others have so far. I wasn't suggesting to distribute Delphi's assembler, I was suggesting to put `asm call ebx end;` in a Delphi source file and check what gets generated from that.

Comment: Oops, you're right, @Hvd! Josh wrote "i.e.," but I read "e.g.," which completely changes the meaning of the question. He indeed only needs to convert a single, specific instruction into machine code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to obtain a machine code of a single assembler instruction `CALL EBX` using Delphi built-in assembler.

```
function CodeSize: Integer;
asm
    lea EAX, @@end
    lea EDX, @@start
    sub EAX, EDX
    JMP @@end
@@start:
    call EBX
@@end:
end;

procedure Code;
asm
    call EBX
end;

function CodeToBytes: TBytes;
var
  I, N: Integer;
  P: PByte;

begin
  N:= CodeSize;
  SetLength(Result, N);
  P:= @Code;
  for I:= 0 to N - 1 do begin
    Result[I]:= P^;
    Inc(P);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should write this so that there is only one instance of the asm block

Comment: Always better to write something once rather than twice. Very easy to do also.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - above `asm` procs have no prolog.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I'd avoid the duplication of Serg's answer and write it like this:

```
function CodeToBytes: TBytes;
var
  StartAddr, EndAddr: Pointer;
begin
  asm
    LEA EAX, @@start
    MOV StartAddr, EAX
    LEA EAX, @@end
    MOV EndAddr, EAX
    JMP @@end
  @@start:
    CALL EBX
  @@end:
  end;
  SetLength(Result, Integer(EndAddr)-Integer(StartAddr));
  Move(StartAddr^, Pointer(Result)^, Length(Result));
end;
```

Obviously you can stick whatever you like in between the start and end labels.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a dummy procedure following the code and substract the two, eg:

```
procedure Code
asm
   call ebx;
end;

procedure CodeEnd;
asm end;

CodeSize :＝ DWORD_PTR(@CodeEnd) - DWORD_PTR(@Code);
CopyMemory(@MyByteArray[0], @Code, CodeSize);
```

Note that in code you use also use Delphi code instead of asm as long as you don't call into other code (functions/procedures/rtl)

EDIT: as an answer to the comments from Serg and David Heffernan I verified the results with Delphi 2010 in release mode.

I used the following code:

```
procedure Code;
asm
  mov eax, 0;
end;

procedure CodeEnd;
asm end;


procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessageFmt('CodeSize=%d', [DWORD_PTR(@CodeEnd) - DWORD_PTR(@Code)]);
end;
```

The reported CodeSize is 8 Bytes, I then verified using Ida Pro (disassembler on the executable):

```
.text:004B3344                 Code            proc near              
.text:004B3344                                                        
.text:004B3344 B8 00 00 00 00                  mov     eax, 0
.text:004B3349 C3                              retn
.text:004B3349                 Code            endp
.text:004B3349
.text:004B3349                 ; -----------------------------
.text:004B334A 8B C0                           align 4
```

So in this example mov eax, 0 is 5 bytes (B8 00 00 00 00), retn (added by compiler) is 1 byte (C3), align 4 is 2 bytes (8B C0) which is 8 in total.

Comment: Not sure that is safe because the compiler can align the start point of the dummy procedure, that is why I used `CodeSize` function.

Comment: @Serg: If it does align (does the compiler do that? I've never seen that) than I surely hopethe compiler inserts NOP's :-)

Comment: Well nop's is ok but even if it was random bytes it shouldn't matter because procedure code ends with a retn

Comment: More important is that your code includes `ret` instruction and CodeSize value is wrong in any case.

Comment: If your code includes the RET, then it differs from the accepted answer.

Comment: I don 't have compiler access right now so I can't check but I think the compiler will add a retn to return from the procedure. Codesize might (in case of alignment) include a few nop's but that's no problem for executing it